# Unix CLI script to rename folders containing space

Tags: regex, bash, unix, rename

I have a directory with folder structure as follows:

```
DATA -- ABD 1231345 -- 2012_01_08
                    -- 2012_03_09
                    -- 2012_06_11

     -- DEF 4859480 -- 2012_02_10
                    -- 2012_05_10
                    -- 2012_07_10
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- `cd DATA`
- run a bash script (while in `/DATA`) that will rename all first-child folders from

> ABD 1231345

to

> ABD_1231345

Do you have a suggestion on how to accomplish using command line on Mac OSX / unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i// /_}"; done
```

Note that the `${i//string/repl}` syntax is a non-standard extension of sh, but you can do the same thing portably with something like:

```
for i in *; do j=$( echo "$i" | tr ' ' _); mv "$i" "$j"; done
```

Comment: william will this recursively go deeper in the folder structure? I just noticed that is necessary

Comment: This does not recurse.  Probably the best thing would be to do something like `find . -exec rename_file {} \;` where rename_file is a simple script (or, if your shell supports exporting functions that find will recognize, a function) that renames the file.

Comment: could your script replace `rename_file`?

Comment: @thor `rename_file` would be much simpler.  Something like:`new_name=${1// /_}; mv $1 $new_name;`

Answer (score 0):

**Current directory contains:**

```
aa 111
bb 222
aaa.txt
aaa 1111.txt
bbb 2222.txt
```

**Output:**

```
aa_111
bb_222
aaa.txt
aaa 1111.txt
bbb 2222.txt
```

**Code:**

```
ls -ltr|awk -F" " '{print $9,$10}'|sed 's/ $//g'|grep -v "^$">abc

while read line
do
val=`echo $line`
echo $line|grep " ">/dev/null
rc=$?
if [[ -d "$val" && $rc -eq 0 ]]
then
replace=`echo $line|sed 's/ /_/g'`
mv "$val" "$replace"
fi
done<abc

rm -f abc
```

Here, above script is renaming the folders only in current directory.You can skip the grep part(its for efficiency).